# Какой тип связи Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица Types:

ID NAME

1  w

2  d

3  f

Где ID - AUTOINCREMENT

---

Есть другая таблица USER_TYPE, которая имеет такую структуру:

ID_USER ID_TYPE

1  w    1

1  d    2

2  w    3

Связь таблиц по ID_TYPE = ID

Т-е каждый из юзер может иметь любой вариант ID из таблицы Types.
Если посмотреть в обратной направлении - то одно значение ID из Types соответствует множеству значений из таблицы USER_TYPE.
Можно утверждать что связь между таблицами Types с таблицей USER_TYPE - как один ко многим? или многие к одному?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Один ко многим" и "многие к одному" - это одно и то же, в зависимости от того, с какой стороны читать связь.